# Error http.get angular

Tags: angularjs, http

I have a problem that is driving me crazy. It's about a mobile app with Ionic / angular and need your help:

In my code,I make a http request for get an array something like this:

```
{"Exist": 0}
```

I'm sure that the server where I make this request is run and receive the request because in the logger I see the request.

I've written some log messages to see where my app have the error and always stop y the .error section.

**`js`**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.factory('validaEmail', function($http) {

    return {
        existeEmail: function($correo){
            console.log("Dentro de validaEmail");
            $http.get("http://www.promozzapp.com/php/validaUser.php?email=" +$correo)
                .success(function(valor1, valor2) {
                    console.log("SUCESS ");
                    window.alert("SUCESS");

                })
                .error(function (data, status, headers, config){
                    console.log("ERROR - "+data+" - "+status);
                    window.alert("ERRORR" + data +  " - "  +status + " - H: " +headers);

                })
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log("**** THEN **** " );
                });
        }   
    };
})
```

**`index.html`**

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' http://www.promozzapp.com  'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: does your `success` Callback code gets called or not? do put `debugger` keyword in both `success` & `error` callback and verify it

Comment: What is the error message? (in the error provided to the `error` callback)

Comment: This appears to be something with your JSON. Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/matiastucci/azc1evjx/1/, with another JSON it works fine. Try setting the header of `validaUser.php` to JSON type

Answer (score 0):

At first, try to enter this url in browser: http://www.promozzapp.com/php/validaUser.php?email=test@example.com

You will see, that it returns invalid JSON string.

Secondly, this url return `text/html` response, not `json`

Your error lays in your backend code in `validaUser.php` file